# Pass parameter request to a celery task in Django

Tags: python, django, django-celery

I have a simple issue, we have as follows:

```
@task()
def upload_image(request):
     var = request.POST

     # ... do something
```

And we call it in another method the delay for this method like this:

`job = upload_image.delay(request)`

This not works obviously, after I read, you can pass messages to a celery task like a simple `arg`, `args` or `kwargs**` but what I just want is to pass a simple object, not a string or list of strings, is there anyway to do this in celery?

Regards!

Answer (score 1):

This does not work with the standard pickler. See more here (basically a duplicate): [passing django request object to celery task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31304095/passing-django-request-object-to-celery-task)

Answer (score 0):

As you can read from the [docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html#defining-and-calling-tasks) your example should work.

```
from celery import task

@task()
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

add.delay(2, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work as long as you're using standard pickle serializer.