# How to pass dajngo request parameter to celery task

Tags: django-rest-framework, celery

Not able to pass Django request parameter to celery task

i am calling the celery task method like this.
My_task((request, application_data.id), task_id=task_id)

And my task method is like this:
@shared_task(name="create-cloud-storage-task")
def My_task(request_data, id):

But it throwing error saying cannot send the request object?
What is wrong in this code

Comment: Since Celery is a distributed system, you can't know in which process, or even on what machine the task will run so it's better to extract the required information through request object and send that to the celery tasks as the parameter.

Comment: But I want all my request parameter to be available in task and parameter count is more than 15. Is it good idea to send 15 parameters to a task

Comment: Then send them as kwargs(key word arguments)

Answer (score 0):

Since the request object contains references to things which aren't practical to serialize — like uploaded files, or the socket associated with the request — there's no general purpose way to serialize it.

Instead, you should just pull out and pass the portions of it that you need. For example, something like:

If you're using user_id in your task, or whatever else you'll be using.

```
My_task((request.user.id, application_data.id), task_id=task_id)

@shared_task(name="create-cloud-storage-task")
def My_task(request_user_id, id):
```

Reference : [passing django request object to celery task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31304095/passing-django-request-object-to-celery-task)