# use celery with Django-verify-email

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery

I am  trying to setup a simple task to send email verification with the django-verify-email package and celery

here is my code

```
#task.py
from celery import shared_task
from verify_email.email_handler import send_verification_email



@shared_task
def send_user_email(request, form):
    inactive_user = send_verification_email(request, form)
```

#sign_up.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from .tasks import send_user_email




def signup(request, form_class, template_name, success_message, redirect_url):

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(redirect_url)
    form = form_class()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            send_user_email(request, form=form)
            messages.success(request, success_message)
            return redirect(redirect_url)
        else:
            messages.error(
                request, f'Error creating account. Please check the form.')
            return render(request, template_name, {'form': form})

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

i have this error on the task console

```
[2024-01-03 19:08:34,231: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-2] Task user.tasks.send_user_email[1f521272-e7e4-4ae0-8fd8-ef1e0ad551e5] raised unexpected: AttributeError("'dict' object has no attribute 'save'")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/foli/code/django/freeacademy/.freemindedAcademy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 477, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/foli/code/django/freeacademy/.freemindedAcademy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 760, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/foli/code/django/freeacademy/user/tasks.py", line 7, in send_user_email
    inactive_user = send_verification_email(request, form_data)
  File "/home/foli/code/django/freeacademy/.freemindedAcademy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/verify_email/email_handler.py", line 94, in send_verification_email
    return _VerifyEmail().send_verification_link(request, form)
  File "/home/foli/code/django/freeacademy/.freemindedAcademy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/verify_email/email_handler.py", line 32, in send_verification_link
    inactive_user = form.save(commit=False)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'save'
```

i have this over error on the web console

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/foli/code/django/freeacademy/.freemindedAcademy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 41, in _reraise_errors
    yield
  File "/home/foli/code/django/freeacademy/.freemindedAcademy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 220, in dumps
    payload = encoder(data)
  File "/home/foli/code/django/freeacademy/.freemindedAcademy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/utils/json.py", line 57, in dumps
    return _dumps(s, cls=cls, **dict(default_kwargs, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/json/__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/home/foli/code/django/freeacademy/.freemindedAcademy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/utils/json.py", line 45, in default
    return super().default(o)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/json/encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '

During handling of the above exception (Object of type WSGIRequest is not JSON serializable), another exception occurred:
  File "/home/foli/code/django/freeacademy/.freemindedAcademy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/foli/code/django/freeacademy/.freemindedAcademy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/foli/code/django/freeacademy/user/views.py", line 128, in teacher_signup
    return signup(
  File "/home/foli/code/django/freeacademy/user/user_signup.py", line 17, in signup
    send_user_email.delay(request, form)
  File "/home/foli/code/django/freeacademy/.freemindedAcademy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 444, in delay
    return self.apply_async(args, kwargs)
  File "/home/foli/code/django/freeacademy/.freemindedAcademy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 594, in apply_async
    return app.send_task(
  File "/home/foli/code/django/freeacademy/.freemindedAcademy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 799, in send_task
    amqp.send_task_message(P, name, message, **options)
  File "/home/foli/code/django/freeacademy/.freemindedAcademy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/app/amqp.py", line 518, in send_task_message
    ret = producer.publish(
  File "/home/foli/code/django/freeacademy/.freemindedAcademy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 175, in publish
    body, content_type, content_encoding = self._prepare(
  File "/home/foli/code/django/freeacademy/.freemindedAcademy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 268, in _prepare
    body) = dumps(body, serializer=serializer)
  File "/home/foli/code/django/freeacademy/.freemindedAcademy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 219, in dumps
    with _reraise_errors(EncodeError):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/contextlib.py", line 153, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(typ, value, traceback)
  File "/home/foli/code/django/freeacademy/.freemindedAcademy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 45, in _reraise_errors
    reraise(wrapper, wrapper(exc), sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/home/foli/code/django/freeacademy/.freemindedAcademy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/exceptions.py", line 34, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/foli/code/django/freeacademy/.freemindedAcademy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 41, in _reraise_errors
    yield
  File "/home/foli/code/django/freeacademy/.freemindedAcademy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 220, in dumps
    payload = encoder(data)
  File "/home/foli/code/django/freeacademy/.freemindedAcademy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/utils/json.py", line 57, in dumps
    return _dumps(s, cls=cls, **dict(default_kwargs, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/json/__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/home/foli/code/django/freeacademy/.freemindedAcademy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/utils/json.py", line 45, in default
    return super().default(o)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/json/encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '

Exception Type: EncodeError at /users/teacher_signup/
Exception Value: Object of type WSGIRequest is not JSON serializable
```

I believe the issue is from the inactive_user variable in the package.
i have tried many configuration but non will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`send_user_email` is a celery task and so any arguments you're passing need to be **serailizable** (see [related topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31304095/passing-django-request-object-to-celery-task)).

You're passing `request` and `form` as arguments, hence the error:

> Object of type WSGIRequest is not JSON serializable

It seems that using `django-verify-email` with celery is not a good choice, since the django `request` object is being used internally a lot, which makes it impossible to refactor in a way to make is task-serializable, without having to rewrite most of the logic.