# How to send django objects to celery tasks?

Tags: python, django, celery, django-serializer

**Hello Awesome People!**

Before my question, I tried these SO posts:

- [Pass parameter request to a celery task in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18549164/pass-parameter-request-to-a-celery-task-in-django)
- [passing django request object to celery task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31304095/passing-django-request-object-to-celery-task)

None of them works!

I want to keep users on a website update with new courses. With a queryset of `Courses`, I want to send them via email.

```
send_daemon_email.delay(instance=instance,all_courses=Course.objects.all())
```

And my function looks like:

```
@shared_task
def send_daemon_email(instance,all_courses):
    ctx = {'instance':instance,'all_courses':all_courses}
    message = get_template("emails/ads.html").render(ctx)
    ''' '''
```

When I tried to send the email to a specific user
The error I got is

> `<User: First Name> is not JSON serializable`

Just because `delay()` from celery got a non serialized data.

**How I can send Django objects to celery task so I can use it in the template**? I know that I can send information needed as python object

```
send_daemon_email.delay(first_name='Name',
      last_name='Lapr',all_courses = [{'title1':'title1',},{'title2':'title2',}])
```

but it would be too much info.

Any hint will be appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: Well you can not pass objects itself, since those are not serializable, but you can for example pass primary keys, etc.

Comment: with the `pk`, I can retrieve the object within the function? that's a good point

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Django objects can't be sent in celery tasks, you can **serialize** with django serializers (`from django.core import serializers`) by providing fields needed in template and the lookup will work like a django object in template

> NOTE: with serializer you will need to dump and load the data

or just convert your queryset to a list like the following:

```
send_daemon_email.delay(
    instance = User.objects.filter(pk=user.pk).values('first_name','last_name'),
    all_courses= list(Course.objects.values('title','other_field'))
)
```

All you need is to provide fields that you really need in template with `values('')`

```
@shared_task
def send_daemon_email(instance,all_courses):
    ctx = {
        'instance': instance,
        'all_courses': all_courses,
    }
    message = get_template("emails/ads.html").render(ctx)
```

In templates `{% for course in all_courses %}{{course}}{% endfor %}` will display all the courses, and `{{ instance.first_name }}` the user

Comment: That's an interesting answer! let me give it a try

Comment: Yeah! it works, `values()` is better than doing the query twice, the answer of @WillemVanOnsem  is a good one, it's more elaborated.

Answer (score 9):

Well typically tools like celery, use a *format* to pass messages. Here JSON is used, and not every Python object can, by default, be turned into a JSON object.

We can however for example pass the primary keys, and then turn these in objects again at the receiver side. So for example:

```
send_daemon_email.delay(
    instance=instance.pk,
    all_courses=list(Course.objects.all().values_list('pk', flat=True))
)
```

and then at the side of the receiver, we can fetch the objects with:

```
@shared_task
def send_daemon_email(instance,all_courses):
    ctx = {
        'instance': User.objects.get(pk=instance),
        'all_courses': Course.objects.filter(pk__in=all_courses)
    }
    message = get_template("emails/ads.html").render(ctx)
```

Of course we do not *per se* need to pass primary keys: any kind of object that can be JSON serialized (or by manually serializing) can be used. Although I would not make it too complicated, usually simple things work better than more complex (which is one of the *credos* of Python).

Comment: Thank you! we do the query twice.  serialize data may be better

Comment: @EuChi: well in case you only need the direct attributes, you can use `model_to_dict`. But serializing has a cost as well: since Python will have to dump and restore the data in a JSON stream.

Comment: There is a problem with this approach is that if the object has been altered before a worker picking a task, then the worker will be working on the altered object and not the same object the task was instantiated with.

Comment: @Coderji: well that works in both ways: if you pass the values, then you might process an outdated object, and thus the invoice your for example generate, might contain the wrong data. Usually the idea should be that you add enough triggers that a new task is scheduled if the object changes.

Comment: @Coderji: passing values also erodes the model "logic", and thus often makes it harder to write the handler effectively: django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/over-use-of-values.html

Comment: Definitely, it depends on the situation. In my case, the job is running per a request from a client and the request should be processed with the data that the client requested. This is very problomatic as if the instance you pass to celery task has relationships and the relationships have their own as well. This goes out of hand and cannot be simply encoded in JSON.

Comment: @Coderji: perhaps you can use `django-simple-history` and thus pass a reference to the "history instance": https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ that way you can see objects at any point in time, and thus basically get the data at the time you submitted the job to the worker.

Comment: That is brilliant, I didn't hear of it! Thanks alot. maybe it is worth updating the answe to cover both situations.